# Looking for lightweight, Windows-compatible IRC client that has desktop notifications

Tags: windows-7, irc

I use IRC very infrequently. Mostly, I just leave it hidden in the system tray and only touch it if someone contacts me first (it's the primary form of real type communication for a FOSS project I work with, although we also have a forum that I prefer to use).

I'm currently using [Hexchat](http://hexchat.github.io/), and my biggest complaint is that I often miss notifications. The only notification that I get is a minor change to the icon in the system tray. What I'd prefer is a desktop notification.

If possible, I'd also like the following features (although desktop notifications is the most important):

- Can auto-join a specific channel on startup
- Can auto-reconnect if connection is lost
- Can display timestamps in UTC

Other than that, I don't really care about anything else.

Alternatively, some way to make Hexchat display desktop notifications would be great.

Comment: I remember Quassel had desktop notifications, at least on Windows 8 (with the new "metro" notifications), but it's been too long since I used it. Also in case you didn't know, you can make hexchat blink the window + taskbar or beep, which are both very noticeable.

Comment: @3ventic Unfortunately, I always keep it minimized to the system tray (so it's out of the way), so blinking in the taskbar doesn't do any good. Sounds aren't very useful since I rarely have sound enabled (and can't be using speakers for chimes, etc at work). I'll take a look at Quassel next time I boot Windows (Hexchat on Linux has the desired desktop notifications).

Answer (score 1):

mIRC with NoNameScript - Been using it for about 10 years.

Works wonderfully, even though NNScript is a bit outdated.

https://msistuff.wordpress.com/2014/05/07/nnscript-4-22-on-mirc-7-32/